# Ubuntu 20.04 slow/frozen after 30 minutres of use

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

When I start my PC everything is snappy and works great, then about 10-60m after boot I'll try to open an application or a folder and I'll just get a beach ball (only when I hover over the dock), then after about 10 seconds, nothing. So I can't open any application or look at my files.

System monitor says I'm using a normal amount of every resource when this happens and the problem disappears when I restart. Everything else works fine when this is happening; I can still watch videos, use my browser, etc., but only if I already had them open before it started.

Comment: Weirdly, I have the exact opposite problem: Firefox, VLC, Anki, etc. applications all work normally and well when they're already open, I just can't open Nautilus or a new application